# How do i create nested json?

Tags: json

Help please. I am trying to use Newtonsoft to serialize the following and can't get it to work. The resulting JSON should look like this Extract from Postman. I just cannot figure out how to structure the adding of the data before running the serialization
Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Required JSON output

```
{
"Line": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "LineNum": 1,
        "Description": "Test Sales Description",
        "Amount": 100,
        "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "SalesItemLineDetail": {
            "ItemRef": {
                "value": "3",
                "name": "Test:Test Item"
            },
            "UnitPrice": 100,
            "Qty": 1,
            "ItemAccountRef": {
                "value": "6",
                "name": "Sales"
            },
            "TaxCodeRef": {
                "value": "6"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Amountlin": 0,
        "DetailType": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "SubTotalLineDetail": {}
    }
],
"TxnTaxDetail": {
    "TotalTax": 0,
    "TaxLine": [
        {
            "Amount": 0,
            "DetailType": "TaxLineDetail",
            "TaxLineDetail": {
                "TaxRateRef": {
                    "value": "7"
                },
                "PercentBased": true,
                "TaxPercent": 20,
                "NetAmountTaxable": 0
            }
        }
    ]
},
"CustomerRef": {
    "value": "2",
    "name": "Test Company"
},
"BillAddr": {
    "Id": "3",
    "Line1": "21 TEST TEST",
    "Line2": "TEST",
    "City": "TEST",
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "PostalCode": "POSTCODE"
},
"ShipAddr": {
    "Id": "3",
    "Line1": "21 TEST TEST",
    "Line2": "TEST",
    "City": "TEST",
    "Country": "United Kingdom",
    "PostalCode": "POSTCODE"
}
```

}

I have created the following objects

```
 public class ItemRef
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemAccountRef
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaxCodeRef
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalesItemLineDetail
    {
        public ItemRef ItemRef { get; set; }
        public int UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public ItemAccountRef ItemAccountRef { get; set; }
        public TaxCodeRef TaxCodeRef { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubTotalLineDetail
    {
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int LineNum { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string DetailType { get; set; }
        public SalesItemLineDetail SalesItemLineDetail { get; set; }
        public SubTotalLineDetail SubTotalLineDetail { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaxRateRef
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaxLineDetail
    {
        public TaxRateRef TaxRateRef { get; set; }
        public bool PercentBased { get; set; }
        public int TaxPercent { get; set; }
        public int NetAmountTaxable { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaxLine
    {
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string DetailType { get; set; }
        public TaxLineDetail TaxLineDetail { get; set; }
    }

    public class TxnTaxDetail
    {
        public int TotalTax { get; set; }
        public List<TaxLine> TaxLine { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerRef
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class BillAddr
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShipAddr
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Line> Line { get; set; }
        public TxnTaxDetail TxnTaxDetail { get; set; }
        public CustomerRef CustomerRef { get; set; }
        public BillAddr BillAddr { get; set; }
        public ShipAddr ShipAddr { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);` ?

Comment: Sorry I should have added what i was trying to do. This doesn't seem to add the data correctly.

Comment: Root root = new Root();

            Line line = new Line();
            line.Id = "1";
            line.LineNum = 1;

            SalesItemLineDetail salesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();

            ItemRef itemRef = new ItemRef();
            itemRef.value = "1";




            string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

Answer (score 0):

You need the set properties of the objects:

```
ItemRef itemRef = new ItemRef();
itemRef.value = "1";

SalesItemLineDetail salesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();
salesItemLineDetail.ItemRef = itemRef;

Line line = new Line();
line.Id = "1";
line.LineNum = 1;
line.SalesItemLineDetail = salesItemLineDetail;

Root root = new Root();
root.Line = new List<Line>();
root.Line.Add(line);

string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

Comment: Ah!!! I see - i will give that a try. Thank you so much for your reply :)